# What are the differences between MLC and SLC SSD drives?

Tags: memory, flash, ssd

SLC SSD drives cost a lot more than MLC SSD drives. Are there actual differences besides cost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SLC_versus_MLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#SLC_versus_MLC) on Wikipedia's SSD article:

> Lower priced drives usually use [multi-level cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) (MLC) flash memory, which is slower and less reliable than [single-level cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell) (SLC) flash memory. This can be mitigated by the internal design structure of the SSD, such as interleaving and more excess capacity for the wear-leveling algorithms to work with.

Comment: best to provide a quote or summary instead of just a link (tho do include the link so we can go read up for more details!)

Comment: quack- thx for clarifying and editing